# Bash find files and filter by date and size

Tags: bash, shell, find, ls

I have a directory with a lot of files in it.
Each day, new files are added automatically.

The filenames are formatted like that : 
[GROUP_ID]_[RANDOM_NUMBER].txt
Example : 012_1234.txt

For every day, for every GROUP_ID (032, 024, 044...etc), I want to keep only the biggest file of the day.

So for example, for the two days 27 and 28 march I have :

```
March 27    -      012_1234.txt      -         12ko
March 27    -      012_0243.txt      -         3000ko
March 27    -      016_5647.txt      -         25ko
March 27    -      024_4354.txt      -         20ko
March 27    -      032_8745.txt      -         40ko

March 28    -      032_1254.txt      -         16ko
March 28    -      036_0456.txt      -         30ko
March 28    -      042_7645.txt      -         500ko
March 28    -      042_2310.txt      -         25ko
March 28    -      042_2125.txt      -         34ko
March 28    -      044_4510.txt      -         35ko
```

And I want to have :

```
March 27    -      012_0243.txt      -         3000ko
March 27    -      016_5647.txt      -         25ko
March 27    -      024_4354.txt      -         20ko
March 27    -      032_8745.txt      -         40ko

March 28    -      032_1254.txt      -         16ko
March 28    -      036_0456.txt      -         30ko
March 28    -      042_7645.txt      -         500ko
March 28    -      044_4510.txt      -         35ko
```

I don't find the right bash ls/find command to do that, somebody have an idea ?

With this command, I can display the biggest file for each day.

```
ls -l *.txt --time-style=+%s |
awk '{$6 = int($6/86400); print}' |
sort -nk6,6 -nrk5,5 | sort -sunk6,6
```

But I want the biggest file of each **GROUP_ID** file of each day.
So, if there is one file for "012" group_id file, of 10ko, I want to display it, even if there is bigger files for others group id...

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. What have you searched for before asking, and what did you find? Based on that, what did you try, and how did it fail?

Comment: I edit my post. I just want some ideas, I don't ask for a clean and complete answer necessarly. Thanks

Comment: And "ko" is your language's abbreviation for kB I guess?

Comment: And `*Z` is actually a placeholder for `*.txt` or your files are actually named according to that wildcard?

Comment: yes, ko=kb    , and I edit my post to replace *.Z by *.txt

Comment: Does your `ls` actually print the file size in human-readable units (did you alias `ls` to something else perhaps?) ... I'm afraid there's still a lot for us to guess here. Maybe see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258589/breaking-down-too-broad-and-trying-to-understand-it

Comment: I don't really understand your comment. The "ls" command is.... classic "ls" command. In my example on top I don't put a real "ls" return, because I want to simplify the problem details for understanding

Comment: `ls` out of the box produces just a number, not rescaled to k or M if it's large. If you expect a solution which perform this scaling, again, that's borderline too broad and not very hard to google separately.

Comment: If you are merely looking for "hints", the obvious should be "sort by date and group, print the max for the previous group when you see a new date and/or a new group (take care to not forget the last one at the end of the file)". But Stack Overflow isn't really suitable for questions which cannot at some point be declared exhaustively answered.

Comment: I think you don't understand nothing at the question. I already google it and don't find anyone who want to do a thing like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself the solution:

```
ls -l | tail -n+2 |
awk '{ split($0,var,"_"); group_id=var[5]; print $0" "group_id }' |
sort -k9,9 -k5,5nr |
awk '$10 != x { print } { x = $10 }'
```

This gives me the biggest file for each group_id, so now I just add to handle the day part.

For information:

`tail -n+2`: hide the "total" part of the `ls` command's output

First awk: get the group_id part (012, 036...) and display it after the original line ($0)

Sort: sort on filename and size

Take the biggest size of each group_id (column 10 added by awk at beginning)